# Lagom + akka-http integration

Tags: scala, akka-http, lagom

What is the simplest solution to integrate **Akka HTTP** service with / into **Lagom**?

I have two services - `akkahttp:8000` and `lagom:9000`, they are serving methods for Angular application. It would be great to have one endpoint for all the services - `x:8888` for `x:8888/akkahttp` and `x:8888/lagom`.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is often solved by using some kind of [reverse proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) that faces clients and forwards traffic to your Akka HTTP and Lagom services over an internal network.

Popular reverse proxy solutions include:

- [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/)
- [nginx](https://nginx.org/)
- [AWS Application Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/applicationloadbalancer/) (for AWS deployments)

[Lightbend ConductR](http://conductr.lightbend.com/) is the recommended and supported deployment environment for Lagom and Akka based services. It includes a built-in, HAProxy-based [dynamic proxy](http://conductr.lightbend.com/docs/2.0.x/DynamicProxyConfiguration) that supports this kind of configuration.